# Populate textArea from textfile

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple text file:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
TextN
```

And would like to create an interface where each time the user presses the next button the text area will be populated with the next text. I guess I have to use an array for that but I am having problems changing the text with the next button. Moreover the code I have only works on Firefox. Does this mean that when I put the website on a server this will be interpreted by Firefox clients only?

```js
function test() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      var contents = xmlhttp.responseText;
      myArray = contents.split("\n");

    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "deeds.txt", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}


function nextDeed() {
  document.getElementById('deed').innerHTML = myArray[0]
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1 align="center" style="font-family:Arial;">RELATION TAGGING </h1>
  <textarea id="deed" rows="15" cols="160"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="nextDeed()" /><br/>
  <div id="result">Result</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the problems I see in your code is that myArray is not declared in the global scope, so either you can have an error "Not declared" or the variable is created and destroyed inside the OnReadyStateChange scope. I would suggest you to create a variable before test() "var myArray = [];" and then fill that variable within the readyState part. Also remember to remove the "\r" chars.
One thing to notice is that you should use some kind of "Loading()" layer, because one could click "Next" before the text has been loaded.

Comment: Perhaps your should put your `<textarea>` and `<input>` into a `<form>`-element. That could be the problem with other browsers. Also you should declare your `HTML` unless it is `HTML5`. It could also be that other browsers prevent JavaScript from accessing the file. Use PHP or ASP for that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```js
step = 0;

$("#next").click(function(){
    step = step +1;
       
       $.ajax({
     url: "./text.php?"+"step="+step,
     success: function(data){
       $("#deed").val(data);
     }
  });
 });

 ;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center" style="font-family:Arial;" >RELATION TAGGING </h1>
 <textarea id="deed" rows="15" cols="160">
 </textarea>
 <input type="button" id="next" value="next" /><br/>
 <div id="result">Result</div>
</body>



</html>
```

```
PHP code : <?php $data  = file_get_contents("file".$_GET["t"].".txt"); echo $data;?>
```

Comment: I have used jquery to accomplish this. The ajax call is handled by php server